# Word meaning to destroy books

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or short phrase, which describes or implies the destruction of books or libraries?

Comment: There’s ***book burning***...

Comment: Fahrenheit 451.

Comment: Maybe you ob*literate* them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word you're looking for is **biblioclasm**.

According to [*Burning Books and Leveling Libraries: Extremist Violence and Cultural Destruction*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=67CWswHay3QC&lpg=PA3&ots=NibyShqIKS&dq=oxford%20english%20dictionary%20%22biblioclasm%22&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=oxford%20english%20dictionary%20%22biblioclasm%22&f=false), By Rebecca Knuth, it appears in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> In the Oxford English Dictionary, *biblioclasm* is defined as "the breaking of books" and cited as first appearing in print in 1864 in a text on religious theory.

After a bit or research I found it on the [Volume I (A-B)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.99992/page/n5) of the Oxford English Dictionary, published in 1913:

[image]

The quality is not good, but one can read:

> **Biblioclasm** Destruction of books, or of the Bible. **Biblioclast**, a destroyer of books, or of the Bible. (Little more than nonce-words). **1864** T. Griffith *Plea Scripture* The Biblioclasm of the 'higher criticism' **1884** [illegible] Made bonfires of the Maya and Aztec manuscripts.. May these bishops expiate their crimes in the purgatory of biblioclasts.

The etymology would be the famous noun βιβλίον (*little book*, or just *book*) and the less known verb κλάω (*to break*). It's worth mentioning that κλάω can also mean *to destroy*, which is a common meaning in biology, like in *osteoclast*.

---

<sub>Note: If you want to coin a new word you can use *bibliopyrosis*, from πῦρ (*fire*). This seems to be completely new, since the [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&ei=C0YkXf2oOIfez7sP1aa-gAU&q=bibliopyrosis&oq=bibliopyrosis&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..6017...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.SD6pX8eYadM) returns nothing.</sub>

Comment: If destroying books were made illegal (the opposite of Fahrenheit 451) then this would be a great name for the crime.  I believe, actually, that in Alexandria, in ancient Greece, in the time of the famous library, it **was** actually illegal to destroy books (which were scrolls, then).   I wonder what they called it, it may even have been biblioclasm.

Comment: Wait, we can suggest words that aren't officially recognized or defined by any respected dictionary, openly declare it's a word that doesn't actually exist in common use, provide a link to some page where someone suggested it might be worth inventing and it's enough to acquire upvotes as if it's a reasonable answer to a sensible question here? What a joke EL&U must be !

Comment: The word is listed in the OED (about as respected a dictionary as one could hope for), along with "biblioclast". It does also say, though, "Little more than nonce-words". Incidentally, I don't like these words because -clasm means _breaking_, and somehow that seems like the wrong term for books.

Comment: I like bibliopyrosis! :) (edit) lol; the google search does return something now - this page! :D

Comment: It’s not often that you get to witness the birth of a new google search result! Thanks!

Comment: "Bibliopyrosis" would seem to apply only to the destruction of books by fire.  Destroying books by other means (water, shredder, etc.) would not be included.

Comment: If we are making them up as we go along, how about _**'Bibliocide'**_

Comment: @CaiusJard - "provide a link to some page where someone suggested it might be worth inventing" - yeah, just like Urban Dictionary, except this is from an *actual* dictionary's 'submission' page (the only problem is if that's not included in plan text in the cite). Wiktionary imo however: you can pack up your gear and get out. The joke is on Stack Exchange as a whole: [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast?page=2&tab=votes)

Answer (score 8):

Since *biblioclasm* is basically unheard of in the English language, and *bibliopyrosis* was **literally** unheard of prior to this question, I think the question deserves an answer that will actually be recognized:

> #### book burning
>
> *noun*
>
> : destruction of writing or pictures regarded as politically or socially harmful or subversive or produced by persons whose ideas or acts are so regarded

<sup>([Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/book%20burning))</sup>

Despite the use of the word “burning,” *book burning* is used to describe the destruction of books for political purposes regardless of the actual method of destruction. The phrase is an allusion to the infamous book bonfires performed by the Nazis, but of course the large-scale destruction of books for political purposes is vastly older than that. It is widely understood, thanks in part to *Fahrenheit 451* and other media, such as *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* which includes a Nazi bonfire.

Answer (score 0):

The term "pulp" is sometimes used to describe recycling already-printed books into fresh proto-paper -- sometimes as a scare tactic.

I've read that some 'vanity' presses have used the threat of pulping unsold books in storage to exact $ from authors (e.g. buy them, pay us more to keep storing them.) But I have no citations of that.

Answer (score -2):

Just to go in a different direction here: [bowdlerize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bowdlerize)
 to modify by abridging, simplifying, or distorting in style or content.